# Ubuntu server 16.04 tty not working

Tags: linux, systemd, configuration, tty, console

I have upgraded my office server to Ubuntu server 16.04, but I have a problem with virtual terminals: they don't open.

The system boot correctly, also ssh works, but if I want to use the console by the server's keyboard, it's not possible because it does not show me the login prompt.

On the principal screen I see a list of green OK, and if I change to other terminals (ctrl+alt+F2 and so) I see a black screen.

I've tried to enable getty with this command

```
systemctl enable getty@.service
```

but it doesn't work.
If I try to force the start of getty on tty1 (for example) with the command

```
systemctl start getty@tty1
```

nothing happened and no errors are displayed.

The only way to start a virtual terminal is with this command

```
service getty@tty1 start
```

I must use ssh to control the server.
I also edited the /etc/systemd/logind.conf file, but nothing is changed.

This is the logind.conf file content

```
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#  under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as
published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.
#
# Entries in this file show the compile time defaults.
# You can change settings by editing this file.
# Defaults can be restored by simply deleting this file.
#
# See logind.conf(5) for details.

[Login]
NAutoVTs=6
ReserveVT=6
#KillUserProcesses=no
#KillOnlyUsers=
#KillExcludeUsers=root
#InhibitDelayMaxSec=5
#HandlePowerKey=poweroff
#HandleSuspendKey=suspend
#HandleHibernateKey=hibernate
#HandleLidSwitch=suspend
#HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore
#PowerKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#SuspendKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#HibernateKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=yes
#HoldoffTimeoutSec=30s
#IdleAction=ignore
#IdleActionSec=30min
#RuntimeDirectorySize=10%
#RemoveIPC=yes
#UserTasksMax=12288
```

How can I get console tty's to show a login prompt on their own?

Answer (score -1):

I had a Ubuntu 16.04 Server fail to load TTY7, but TTY1-6 worked.  If `systemctl start` works, you can use enable.

`sudo systemctl enable getty@tty1`